# Should I set up SSH or a VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, remote-desktop

I currently RDP to my home PC using a secure SSH tunnel. It works well but I would like to try to set up a VPN.

My understanding is that if I connect to the VPN from a remote PC, all the traffic of that PC will go through my home network (including Internet). Is that correct? If it is the case, is there a way to limit the VPN to RDP only? For instance, I wouldn't like all the traffic on my work PC to go through my home network.

Thanks!

Comment: Your VPN can be configured to either route all of your traffic, or just to accept traffic destined for a particular subnet (ie your home network).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on whether your vpn solution supports split tunneling or not. at my work, once im on the VPN, all traffic routes through my work (which also prevents me printing to my network printer). At my previous job, only my work's networks were routed through the vpn, so local traffic stayed local, internet traffic went out my network connection, and work traffic went through the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable `split tunnelling` so `RDP` (and any other traffic to services running within your home network) goes over the `VPN` connection. I'm not aware though of being able to select on an application basis but it may be possible. Either way `split tunnelling` is what you're after.

But, assuming the encryption details are the same I don't think you get any added security benefit if that's what you're after. You may find that running a `VPN` server has added benefits other than simple security - ease of use, ability to easily use other home services without having to create new tunnels etc,  but it may require more to maintain.

Hope this helps